# Failing Selenium tests on chrome in concurrency starting from Chrome Browser version 95

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, watir

we are using:
Selenium: 3
Chrome Version  : 95

The problem:

We have a selenium test suit ( written in Watir + Ruby) which runs in concurrency of 25 on a ubuntu amazon EC2 node.
Starting from chrome version 95 we experience massive test failures with the following error:
timed out after 10 seconds, Element not present in 10 seconds (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError).

while the element is present on the screen as test screenshot shows in our report.
The problem does not reproduce when running the tests one after another. (non-parallel). It also did not reproduce locally on our MacOs machines.

We tried:
-To increase the timeouts - did not help
-Run headless - seems to resolve some of the issues but cause others.
-Decreasing screen resolution - which helped to reduce significantly the amount of test failures

We added bug to chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1271067

Comment: Tough to troubleshoot this without more info. Do the 'element not present' errors happen when a page may not be done loading? Does the issue happen when you run in parallel but less than 25? To be honest it sounds like your system under test is getting overwhelmed. Did you override the default 30 seconds timeout in watir?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, when we are running with only one run there is no issue. We did override the default timeout. Just want to remind that in Chrome version 94 everything working fine as it is now, the problem started only from version 95

Comment: What about > 1  and < 25? Is 25 just overwhelming things, or is there something about running in parallel in general? Have you tried reverting to Chrome v94 and verified that it works as expected? The timing might be coincidental (it's really hard to think of a scenario where a Chrome version change causes what you are seeing). Finally, if the site is under heavy load, increasing the timeout from 10 might help.

Comment: Thank you for reply. We reverted to Chrome 94 and everything worked fine again, but we can not update to future versions. In Chrome 95 we ran with < 25, 10 for example. The result were better but still we had number of fails because of concurrent runs. With Chrome 94 we did not have any overwhelming problems on our site.

Comment: I'm at a loss for that, then, as I'm not aware of any changes in Chrome 95 that would cause this kind of problem. This still sounds like a resources issue to me. Make sure that the machine running the code is not running out of resources, and see if you can check the logs for the System Under Test to make sure it is not running out of resources. Does increasing the timeout value back to 30 help?

Comment: #Alex were you able to solve this issue? If yes, can you please post detailed steps on how you are able to do a work around? We also see the same issue starting chrome 95 and above versions, and stuck on 94 for our CI runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved: The problem was that on an AWS EC2 instance there is no actual display. The team was using xvfb (Xvfb or X virtual framebuffer). The test execution used to initiate 1 virtual display for the entire test execution and for some reason, when chrome on that EC2 instance was upgraded to v95 caused the problems described when running concurrently.

Solution: A virtual display was initiated for each test by that eliminating the interference caused by concurrent execution on the EC2.

Comment: can you please post the solution that worked for you. I mean how you initiated the virtual display for each test?

We have been stuck with this issue for parallel tests in our CI since chrome 95

Comment: We create concurrent runs by grouping our tests and then executing each group with xvfb-run -n #{rand(100..10000)} cucumber .... {additional parameters and command string}

Comment: so you set the resolution as part of the additional parameters?